How do I solve my clipping issue?
Hello fellow Blenderers,
So I'm creating an animation in blender and I keep running into this clipping planes issue. I am using grease pencil, a 2d plane, in the 3d world and that may be causing some issues I'm not familiar with but my issues are that:

I cannot zoom in past a certain point (which is extremely frustrating when trying to draw)
When I toggle the Clip start and end options, making the range larger and smaller I am met with a clipping gray screen anytime I try to move the cursor.
I am unsure, but I turned down the resolution of the overall scene to 640x480 because I am aiming for a vhs recording effect. I don't know if this has anything to do with the clipping I am experiencing.

I have included a couple of screenshots so you can see what I see when the clipping occurs. Any help would be greatly appreciated.


